# How to input punctuation into LaTeX header (fancyheadings)?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am following this guide here http://www.fi.infn.it/pub/tex/doc/orig/fancyheadings.pdf

for latex 'fancyheadings' header formatting options. On page 5 it gives an example of how to make the headers on each page the chapter and chapter title.

So for example - the code they give:

```
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\slshape \rightmark}]{\fancyplain{}%
{\slshape \leftmark}}
```

would yield:

`"Chapter 1 Introduction"` on the output page header, where Chapter 1 is the Chapter, and Introduction is the Chapter Title derived from `\chapter{Introduction}` at the beginning of my chapter page.

My question is - how the heck can I make the headers yield something like:

`"Chapter 1: Introduction"` or `"Chapter 1 | Introduction"` or something with some punctuation in between the chapter and the chapter title.

Please let me know if I should post more code -- I am hoping somebody just knows the answer quickly, but let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: `fancyheadings` has been obsolete for many years; actually all it does is issuing a warning to load `fancyhdr` instead (and loads it).

Comment: This is easy to obtain with the `titleps` package which comes with `titlesec`, but can be used independently.

Comment: You could do it with `fancyhdr`, too. But there's no minimal example to play with .... The puzzle sounds interesting, but not interesting enough if I have to create the puzzle before I can play with it.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation issued in 1996 should be suspiciously looked at. Indeed, the `fancyheadings` package has been obsolete for about 20 years.

You have to look at `fancyhdr` documentation and to redefine `\chaptermark`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\slshape\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
      Chapter \thechapter\ $|$ % with a space!
    \fi
    #1%
  }}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can customize it using the following:

- For the chapter name use `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }` where `#1` is the chapter name. You can for instance replace `#1` with `\textit{#1}` and the chapter name will be italic in the headers. The same concept applies to the section name `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1} }`
- The word `Chapter` can be changed using `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}`. You can use an abbreviated form like `Ch`
- The headers are customized using `\fancypagestyle` and the pagestyle
  is defined using `\pagestyle{mainmatter}`. To remove page styles from
  undesired locations (especially at the beginning), use
  `\thispagestyle{empty}`

Here is a full code that will get you `Chapter 1: Introduction` for headers:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{thesis}

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}

        \pagestyle{fancy} % allows for more advanced header and footer formats

                % Customizations
                \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }  % customize chapter name here
                \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}
                \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1} } % customize section name here

                % Define headers
                \fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{
                                                % Header and footer lines
                                                \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5 pt}
                                                \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0 pt}

                                                % Headers
                                                \fancyhead{} % clear header field
                                                \fancyhead[RO]{ \textbf{ \chaptername\ \thechapter:\ \leftmark } \hspace{4mm} \thepage } % customize chapter name header here
                                                \fancyhead[LE]{ \thepage \hspace{4mm} \thesection \textbf{ \rightmark }  } % customize section name header here

                                                % Foot
                                                \fancyfoot{} % clear foot fields
                                                \fancyfoot[LE, RO]{By: Al-Motasem I. Aldaoudeyeh}
                                        }


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\title{Development of a Generalized PV Model in MATLAB/Simulink Using Datasheet Values}



\author{Al-Motasem I. Aldaoudeyeh
    \thanks{Al-Motasem I. Aldaoudeyeh is with the Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering, North Dakota State University, Fargo, ND, 58102 USA e-mail: almotasem.aldaoudeye@ndsu.edu}
}


\maketitle


\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{abstract}

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\pagestyle{mainmatter}
\chapter{Chapter Name}


\section{Introduction}
\label{section:introduction}

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.


\section{Numerical Results and Discussion}
\label{sec:results}

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.

    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit.


\section{Conclusions}
\label{sec:conclusions}


    This paper proposes an improved single-diode modeling approach for PV modules suitable for a broad range of the PV technologies available today, including modules on tandem cell structures. After establishing the model (which has an overall of seven parameters), the paper devises a methodology to estimate its parameters using Standard Test Conditions (STC) data, Nominal Operating Cell Temperature (NOCT) data, and temperature coefficients values as provided in most manufacturers' datasheets. Simulation results and their comparison with a previous work show a very accurate prediction of critical points in the current-voltage characteristics curve. The precise prediction happens for both STC and NOCT conditions and the error in predicting maximum power point lies within $1\%$ limit, and the error in its corresponding voltage and current is almost always within $2\%$ limit. Further, for both maximum power point and open-circuit voltage, the statistical variance around manufacturer measurements due to temperature changes is demonstrated to be low for five various module technologies.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is that class coming from? Are you sure the OP uses the class?